# Swift - Pod images not loading (not found, returns nil)

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I’ve created a new pod component as per instructions on CocoaPods website. Now I have the following structure within my Pods:

> - Pods (folder)
>
>   - MyComponent (folder)
>
>     - MyComponent.swift
>     - Resources (folder)
>
>       - name_of_image.png

However, when I try to call:

```
UIImage(named: “name_of_image”)
```

from MyComponent.swift, I get a "nil" return.

I’ve read solutions that include creating a bundle for my component, but I haven’t found a proper way to generate it myself. Any advice would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can't (shouldn't) use `UIImage(named:)` within a Pod. This will load an image from your app instead of from the Pod.

You need to get your Pod's `NSBundle` first and then use it to load the image. You can get the `NSBundle` using any class from your Pod.

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: ClassFromYourPod.self)
let image = UIImage(named: "xyz", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But, it still doesn't solve my issue as I'm still getting nil for the UIImage. As I said, I don't have a MyClassName.bundle anywhere in the pod. I just have a Resources folder and the images within.

Comment: Your Pod **is** the bundle. Every Pod is it's own bundle. You need a class from within your Pod (a real class, not a bundle file!) so that Objective-C can find the `NSBundle` of your Pod.

Comment: This worked for me. @Armin, you might want to create a wrapper class *in your pod*, for example : `class Image { let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: Image.self); let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage.png", in bundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)}`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me if you import a `png` directly without `xcassets`

```
    let bundle = Bundle(for: ClassInsidePod.self)
    let image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName", in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
    imageView.image = image
```

But, if you are testing in the `Example` project, you need to update the pods in that project with `pod update`. In my case, before doing that, it was always returning `nil`

Comment: Confirm. As for me, 
pod update 
solved the issue as well.